# Where to Start With Contributing to Ubuntu (and other distros)

Tags: c++, c, open-source, ubuntu

The learning days of my development started with C++, but the days since then have been many.  I would like to look into contributing to Ubuntu (or Chromium), but I'm not sure where to start.  I am extremely rusty when it comes to C++ and especially in such a large project.  Is there a good place for me to start?

I'm mainly looking for resources on where to start in the plethora of code (since there's SO much code) and hopefully a helpful blog/tutorial for picking back up on C++ (preferably directed towards large open-source projects like Ubuntu)

Comment: Note: The Linux kernel is C, not C++.

Comment: @delnan The Linux kernel is only a very small part of Ubuntu.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ubuntu is a distribution, that means it's a bunch of programs packed together in a nice way. You can contribute in many ways to distributions: maintaining package repositories, checking for bugs, artwork... If you're interested in the programming side, I'm sure you'll enjoy fixing bugs for the many packages that Ubuntu is made of (which are open source projects on their own.) Think of it as a layered approach, and you've got to settle in a layer to help.

Dive into their bugtrackers, find a bug, fix it and submit the patch.

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of c++ projects that come to mind: LibreOffice and KDE.

LibreOffice has already made a list of easy hacks so you should start there http://wiki.documentfoundation.org/Easy_Hacks

KDE has also a few tasks marked as Junior Jobs:
http://techbase.kde.org/Contribute/Junior_Jobs

As a rule of thumb the place to start contributing to a project is the bug tracker. Also start following the project from their public VCS compile->run->report bug->provide patch.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a C++ coder, so I can't help there beyond Googling for tutorials, but if you want to figure out where to start in any open source project, the easiest way is to check out their bug tracker, find a bug, and try to fix it. If you try to dive into something like Ubuntu without direction, you're likely to get lost and overwhelmed.

You can find Ubuntu's bug tracker here: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

I bealive you would be more interested on Chromium project for a setout. The browser code can be manipulated on Linux, Windows and Mac with the more appropriate tools. They have a IRC channel too, there you can clarify your doubts.
Generally, when you get on great code, it is allways good to resort to the one with more means to do things quickly and easier. Google has a lot of tools and informations that fit to start-up programmers.

There is a list of help-wanted tasks on http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/list?q=label:helpwanted&can=2.

Claudio M. Souza Junior
Developer

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to start contributing to the Linux kernel itself(written in C, not C++) the lecture [Write and Submit your first Linux kernel Patch](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LLBrBBImJt4) given at the [FOSDEM](http://fosdem.org) conference by [Grek Groah Hartman](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greg_Kroah-Hartman), core member of the Linux Kernel team himself, is a great start and motivating factor. As a bonus point, the advices and contributing points revealed in the lecture are applicable to any other open source project in my opinion.

There's nothing standing in your way to contributing to Open Source. Start right now with as low as documentation, minor bug fixing or even adding/improving or fixing grammar issues with comments to existing code. All of these are important and they also help develop your knowledge about a given project or part of a project, which will then enable you to dive deeper in more complex aspects of your chosen project.